# AWS Lambda - removing Python packages to speed up deployment and execution

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda, zappa

Working to update an AWS Lambda function that relies on Flask / zappa that was originally written by another programmer.  If Python modules are not imported / used by the scripts that are running in Lambda, can I remove them without any problem from `requirements.txt`?

The example [file](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/blank-python/function/requirements.txt) provided by AWS seems to have very few requirements.  I just want to make sure that Cloudwatch continues to work and I'm not deleting things that AWS depends on implicitly.

Some of the packages that I am considering removing (since not imported by the Python scripts) include:

- `durationpy`
- `pyrsistent`
- `placebo`
- `pytz`
- `pycparser`
- `troposphere`
- `boto3`

i.e. removing `pyarrow` and `scikit-learn` cut the redeploy time down from 3 minutes to 2 minutes.  AWS Lambda also uses less RAM over shorter duration to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say as the dependencies vary across applications.

As far as I know, `scikit-learn` is a huge library and is not used by AWS. However, if your application or another package in your application uses it as a dependency, removing it might break your application.

Similarly `pyarrow` is also used by many packages. Some of the packages of your application could be using it internally.

I'm not sure but `boto3` can also be removed as it's always available by default by AWS. But you might want to keep it since you'll be needing it for running the application locally.

For all other packages, I suggest you create a dependency tree of your packages using [pipdeptree](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree)
This will serve as starting point to determine which can could be removed.

Comment: Thanks, will use `pipdeptree`.  The packages are installed from the AWS shell using `pip`.  If a flask package depended on `pyrsistent`, wouldn't pip install it if it weren't already installed?

Comment: When the lambda function is deployed, it only installs packages present in the requirements.txt. 
If a flask package depends on it, the installation or deployment might fail. This is why `pip freeze` is important. It may work on your machine but you never know how it might behave when it deploys